# How do I determine the DataSource being used by a Hibernate Session?

Tags: java, hibernate, junit, hsqldb

I have several unit tests that should be using a HSQLDB but I know some of them are actually hitting a physical DB. I want to add a check to the test to make sure that the DataSource being used is for HSQLDB and not the live DB.

From a hibernate session object (`org.hibernate.classic.Session`), How do I check the DataSource

***Update:**
I also have access to the session factory (`org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactory`).*

***Details:** Hibernate 3.2*

Comment: There are a lot of in-house proprietary wrappers around the tests. It is an extension on `org.springframework.test.AbstractTransactionalDataSourceSpringContextTests `

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regardless of wrappers and concrete implementation of Hibernate/Spring and so on, you may check not DataSource, but database type (and this might be suitable).

The idea is in the usage of [DatabaseMetaData](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) and check type against it (as Hibernate detects dialect):

```
private boolean isTestDb(Session session) {
    return session.doReturningWork(new ReturningWork<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
            DatabaseMetaData metaData = connection.getMetaData();
            return metaData.getDatabaseProductName().startsWith("HSQL");
        }
    });
}
```

Note, that body of method can be changed in the way you want (check JDBC URL, check driver name, check almost anything).

**Edit**: approach above is working for hibernate 3.5+.

For Hibernate earlier version(e.g. 3.2) it might be even easier:

```
private boolean isTestDb(Session session) {
    Conection connection = session.connection();//deprecated method, which was dumped in hibernate 3.5+
    DatabaseMetaData metaData = connection.getMetaData();
    return metaData.getDatabaseProductName().startsWith("HSQL");
}
```

Comment: That is fantastic, however I am using hibernate 3.2 which does not have that rather awesome bit of functionality.

Answer (score 3):

If it's a subclass of `AbstractTransactionalDataSourceSpringContextTests`, then have you tried
`getJdbcTemplate().getDataSource()`?

Otherwise you could try

```
((SessionImplementor) session).getJdbcConnectionAccess().obtainConnection()
       .getMetaData().getDatabaseProductName()
```

But it that's kind of disgusting. :) And seems to get introduced in Hibernate 4.x.

#### Edit:

On older versions use the now deprecated:

```
    ((SessionImpl) session).getSessionFactory().getConnectionProvider()
                           .getConnection().getMetaData().getDatabaseProductName();
```

Comment: getJdbcTemplate() returns null

Comment: getJdbcConnectionAccess() does not appear to be a method on SessionImplementor (`org.hibernate.engine.SessionImplementor`)

Answer (score 1):

This is a total hack and might not work since you need to cast to specific classes that your setup might not be using.

```
SessionFactoryImpl factory = (SessionFactoryImpl) session.getSessionFactory(); // or directly cast the sessionFactory
DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl provider = (DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl)factory.getConnectionProvider();
DataSource dataSource = provider.getDataSource();
```

`factory.getConnectionProvider()` returns a `ConnectionProvider` (an interface) instance that can be implemented [by any number of classes](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/service/jdbc/connections/spi/ConnectionProvider.html). One of these is `DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl`, which you can then use to get the datasource.

`DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl` should be the default, unless you are using the hibernate C3P0 or Proxool pools.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to detect db provider without opening new connection you may find it useful to use dialect class.

```
    String dialectName = ((SessionFactoryImplementor)sessionFactory).getDialect().getClass().getSimpleName().toLowerCase();
    if(dialectName.contains("oracle"))
        ...
    else if(dialectName.contains("mysql"))
        ...
```